# usage of `def` vs `lazy val` vs `val` for configuration properties in Scala

Tags: scala, configuration, app-config, lazy-initialization, typesafe

I have an application which is capable of reloading the properties whenever they are changed while the application is running i.e., on the fly!

I created a Singleton to hold all the configuration properties which my application needs so that I do not have to import my "PropertyLoader" library at "n" places in my code. All the properties are `val`s inside the Singleton. I then import this object wherever I need the property. Is it a good practice to store configuration properties in a Singleton like this ?

My next question is:  Should I make these `val`s as `def`s so that the new value for a property will get reflected when its changed ? Or should I change them to `lazy val`s so that I am benefitted if the initialization of a property throws an exception (for example: wrong type), it will attempt to reinitialize the val at next access. (Btw. I tested this behavior of `lazy val` after reading Viktor Klang's tweet: https://twitter.com/viktorklang/status/104483846002704384

Does typesafe config library (https://github.com/typesafehub/config) have any takeaways in this regard ?

Comment: *Is it a good practice to store configuration properties in a Singleton like this ?* No, if you're willing to do reloads.

Comment: @om-nom-nom So my other options would be storing them in a `class` or a `trait`. Do you suggest storing it as a val or def in the class or trait ? Is my configuration file read each time when someone accesses the class which mixes this ConfigurationTrait ?